# obtener texto de un div hijo

Tags: javascript, html

tengo un div con un id, dentro de este tengo otro div con un texto, ese texto es el que quiero extraer, pero me aparece solo "[object HTMLDivElement]".

(el codigo tiene un icono, que al pulsarlo obtengo el id de dos padres superiores, y luego con ese id obtengo su getelementbyid

he intentado con text, textcontent y un monton de mas parametros sin exito.

necesito que me aparezca el texto del medicamento... pero no se en lo que estoy fallando.
Gracias.

```js
function borrareste(esteid){
    console.log("borrareste");
  const idDiv = esteid.parentElement.parentElement.id;
  console.log("id del padre a borrar: "+idDiv)
var divaborrar=document.getElementById(idDiv)
//divaborrar.remove();
 divaborrar.textContent;
   console.log("texto: "+divaborrar);
};
```

```css
.borrarmedicamento{
color: #B6BD99;
}
.rowunafila{
  height: 27px;
  padding-left: 0px !important;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
}
.collistamed{
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
}

.colbusquedamedicon{
    position: relative;
    left: -7px;
}


.colunafilaicon{

    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    top: -3px;
    position: relative;
}
.colbusquedamedicon{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
}

.colunafila{
  font-size: 0.65rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="med2" class="row rowunafila bordenaranja">asdf
<div class="col s10 colunafila">
                                      - IBUPROFENO (ARGININA) CINFA 400 mg GRANULADO PARA SOLUCION ORAL EFG
 </div>
 <div class="col s2 colunafilaicon">
<span  class="material-icons borrarmedicamento"onclick="borrareste(this)">close</span>
</div>                                    
</div>
  
  
  <div id="med3" class="row rowunafila bordenaranja">bbbb
<div class="col s10 colunafila">
                                      - IBUPROFENO (ARGININA) CINFA 400 mg GRANULADO PARA SOLUCION ORAL EFG
 </div>
 <div class="col s2 colunafilaicon">
<span  class="material-icons borrarmedicamento"onclick="borrareste(this)">close</span>
</div>                                    
</div>
  
  
  <div id="med4" class="row rowunafila bordenaranja">cccc
<div class="col s10 colunafila">
                                      - IBUPROFENO (ARGININA) CINFA 400 mg GRANULADO PARA SOLUCION ORAL EFG
 </div>
 <div class="col s2 colunafilaicon">
<span  class="material-icons borrarmedicamento"onclick="borrareste(this)">close</span>
</div>                                    
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estás poniendo en el log el elemento y no el texto del elemento. Guarda en una variable el resultado de `divaborrar.textContent` y luego por consola muestra el resultado.

Y si quieres el resultado solo del `<div>` hijo busca por [firstElementChild](http://www.w3bai.com/es/jsref/prop_element_firstelementchild.html). Te dejo tu función con algo más de código para mostrar ambas salidas:

```
function borrareste(esteid){
    console.log("borrareste");
    const idDiv = esteid.parentElement.parentElement.id;
    console.log("id del padre a borrar: "+idDiv)
    var divaborrar=document.getElementById(idDiv)
    var texto = divaborrar.textContent;
    var textoHijo = divaborrar.firstElementChild.textContent;
    console.log("texto: "+texto);
    console.log("texto: "+textoHijo);
}
```

Espero te sirva de ayuda

Comment: muchas gracias... si, se me pasó justo o que comentaste... tambien encontré otro metodo mas lioso
.childNodes[1].lastChild.
que te da el primer nodo(por si hay varios)

Comment: De nada! Lo bueno (y malo a la vez) de la programación es que hay diferentes maneras de hacer las cosas. A veces lo hacemos de una manera directa, y otras damos un montón de vueltas ... Me alegro de que te haya servido!